# KQL Query to calculate time difference between multiple statements

Tags: kql, azure-log-analytics

```
timestamp [IST]                 OperationID                       Message
2022/30/6, 4:10:00.460 AM   fbf759a0-d4be-4d07-adfb-7090a207e667  Work flow Started
2022/30/6, 4:12:00.091 AM   fbf759a0-d4be-4d07-adfb-7090a207e667  External Work Flow1 Started
2022/30/6, 4:10:00.460 AM   fbf759a0-d4be-4d07-adfb-7090a207e667  External Work Flow2 Started
2022/30/6, 4:14:10.791 AM   fbf759a0-d4be-4d07-adfb-7090a207e667  External Work Flow1 Ended
2022/30/6, 4:15:10.460 AM   fbf759a0-d4be-4d07-adfb-7090a207e667  External Work Flow2 Ended
2022/30/6, 4:20:04.343 AM   fbf759a0-d4be-4d07-adfb-7090a207e667  Work flow Ended
```

Hi Team,

I am looking for a help on KQL which display the processing time overall and external component processing times
For Example: For above table we need an output like in seconds

```
Operation ID                           EndtoEndTimings    ExternalWorkflow1Timings  ExternalWorkflow2Timings
fbf759a0-d4be-4d07-adfb-7090a207e667     600 sec          120 sec                   300 sec
```

Appreciate if any one can help on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have reproduced in my environment and got expected results as below:

The below KQL query which worked for me:

```
let x= datatable(timestamp:datetime,OperationID: string,Message: string)[
 "2022-06-30 04:10:00.460" ,"fbf759a0-d4be-4d07-adfb-7090a207e667","Work flow Started"
   ,"2022-06-30 04:12:00.091" ,"fbf759a0-d4be-4d07-adfb-7090a207e667","External Work Flow1 Started"
   ,"2022-06-30 04:10:00.460" ,"fbf759a0-d4be-4d07-adfb-7090a207e667","External Work Flow2 Started"
   ,"2022-06-30 04:14:10.791" ,"fbf759a0-d4be-4d07-adfb-7090a207e667","External Work Flow1 Ended"
   ,"2022-06-30 04:15:10.460" ,"fbf759a0-d4be-4d07-adfb-7090a207e667","External Work Flow2 Ended"
   ,"2022-06-30 04:20:04.343" ,"fbf759a0-d4be-4d07-adfb-7090a207e667","Work flow Ended"
];
let t1=x
|summarize EndtoEndTimings=round((max(timestamp) - min(timestamp)) / 1s) by OperationID;
let t2=x
|where Message contains "External Work Flow1 Started" or Message contains "External Work Flow1 Ended"
|summarize ExternalWorkflow1Timings=round((max(timestamp) - min(timestamp)) / 1s) by OperationID;
let t3=x
|where Message contains "External Work Flow2 Started" or Message contains "External Work Flow2 Ended"
|summarize ExternalWorkflow2Timings=round((max(timestamp) - min(timestamp)) / 1s) by OperationID;
let t4=t1
|join kind=inner t2 on OperationID;
t4
| join kind=inner t3 on OperationID
| project-away OperationID1,OperationID2
```

**`Output:`**

[image]

[Fiddle](https://dataexplorer.azure.com/clusters/help/databases/Samples?query=H4sIAAAAAAAAA62UT2vDIBjG7/kULzk1kHTG2IRm5LYOdhg7bLDD2MFU09kmWoyl2eiHnxkZy1pa%20g9BUB/fn48%20WHIDTQaMGtvykg%20MqHhtaLVM7RxvR/7TkmtqhJIPdynURgs58x95XdMZ/x17bw64GGEcoDiIECCShihFaEhi5ILvFnmRjMYUBYzkPCAMJQFlRR4kaIwoRgmP48T13VelF1CUag3PhmrDmesA2O1blXFbGY3DEypPGsO1pCX8IO4tIjzMOOP0uwx8mNFihsnFPiaS7SOMWsLlLvYTsL0nMoxIdNYrd3Xfb53S5tCEWeNs6lVVUS2%20eLtqlO1eRGUjVmdarSQbDCra/KXUgwDsam/CgxsIaw/yT%20gFtyPglrD%204JpDl2CYKmmokDUczAgofeSOzlPfR6dqRa3t8IqGotMM4ZMN4SMM4SsaIpkJnc1cCQkLIVkmpOTaPhwo%20V9tiLOBHV20pbOapVZzPjUBXdN/wLD/seFvsW0mEQkFAAA=).

Comment: Thanks RithwikBojja, It works like charm. Appreciate your help